# Pagination and "if" condition

Tags: entries, pagination, merge

Some of my entries have the same entry.title. At the frontend, I would like to display these entries only once. This works with the following code:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries().section('produkte').relatedTo(category) %}
{% set existingtitle = [] %}
 {% for entry in entries %}
  {% if entry.title not in existingtitle %}        
    {{ Display the Results }}
  {% endif %}
  {% set existingtitle = existingtitle|merge([entry.title]) %}
 {% endfor %}
```

My question is: How can I then paginate these results? For example 9 entries per page?
If I paginate before the "if" condition gives me not the required result.
Any help or tips are highly appreciated!

Comment: For issue 1 you could create another query on your second page using the offset function. So .limit(1).offer(8). This should get you the 9th entry. Also I would consider looping through your returned data and maybe reordering into a new array with the title as a key maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build an array of the filtered results, then paginate that.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries().section('produkte').relatedTo(category) %}
{% set filteredEntries = [] %}
{% set existingtitle = [] %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% if entry.title not in existingtitle %}
        {% set filteredEntries = filteredEntries|merge([entry]) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set existingtitle = existingtitle|merge([entry.title]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then modify this code to paginate array: https://gist.github.com/juban/a55781d49f2f68ec3ca47979bcaaa49a

Comment: This gives me the error message: **TypeError: Argument 1 passed to craft\helpers\Template::paginateCriteria() must implement interface yii\db\QueryInterface, array given, ...**

Comment: My mistake, I thought you could paginate arrays. This tweet might be helpful to you: https://twitter.com/juban/status/1139207162159386625

Comment: Even better, a gist: https://gist.github.com/juban/a55781d49f2f68ec3ca47979bcaaa49a have updated answer to reflect

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try this

Comment: I could solve it, with this code: https://gist.github.com/juban/a55781d49f2f68ec3ca47979bcaaa49a, thanks a lot to user3788089 for this information!